# unable to start namenode after formatting in centos7

Tags: hadoop, centos7

I am unable to start namenode in hdp 2.3.4 centos 7 after running the format command. I am getting below error: Error: Cannot find configuration directory: start
 Below is the bashrc file:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
 fi
```

## User specific environment and startup programs

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export JAVA_HOME=$PATH/jdk1.7.0_71
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$PATH/hadoop-2.3.4
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

Below is the command I am executing to start namenode:

```
/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-namenode/../hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start namenode
```

Comment: PATH variable is ment to hold a list of directories. I'm not sure if it affects you or not, but there is definitely something wrong here: export HADOOP_INSTALL=$PATH/hadoop-2.3.4

Comment: Try removing `$PATH` from java, Hadoop install

Comment: no differnece to the better it actually worsened. Unable to sudo to $HDFS_USER now

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Error: Cannot find configuration directory:

is thrown because the variable $HADOOP_CONF_DIR, used in the command, is not set in the environment and is trying to start namenode with no actual config `--config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR` path.

After fixing the environment variable assignments, the .bashrc should look like this (assumed the installation is thru tarballs)

```
export JAVA_HOME=/<absolute_path_where_jdk_is_extracted>/jdk1.7.0_71
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/<absolute_path_where_hdp_is_extracted>/hadoop-2.3.4
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `.bashrc` with below parameters

```
export JAVA_HOME= location of the JAVA_home (/usr/java/jdk1.x.x)
export HADOOP_HOME=location of the HADOOP_HOME (User defined)
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export PATH
```

Note: Hadoop installed location should be with `HADOOP_HOME`, it will reflext in `hadoop-env.sh`